# Paperwork issues - Swift_TransportException 'Cannot send message without a sender address'

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer, password-recovery

[image: The thrown exception]

I have a virtual machine running paperwork from GitHub, I use it in my organization for users to write notes but now I've run into an issue with the password recovery, when I try to ask for a password recovery this happens:

I'm getting the 'Cannot send message without a sender address' exception from the swift mailer, I can't seem to find where to set up the sender address.

I have tried to specify the sender in the message creation function in `message.php` as `$this->setFrom('email@example.com');`
This makes the exception go away but I don't receive any password recovery mail sent to my inbox.

Comment: put the entire code here please (only the mailer sender code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you have set the `from` in `app/config/mail.php`

```
'from' => ['address' => 'myname@gmail.com', 'name' => 'myname']
```

And don't forget to do `php artisan config:cache` after.